# タグのシンタックスハイライト設定で選べるオプションが足りない

Tags: バグ, 完了, シンタックスハイライト

モデレーター権限で、タグごとにデフォルトのシンタックスハイライト言語を設定できるようになっています。が、[ハイライトエンジンが対応している言語](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/157841)の全てが設定できるわけではないようです。

現在のオプション一覧:

```
<none>
default
lang-bsh
lang-c
lang-cpp
lang-cs
lang-csh
lang-css
lang-hs
lang-html
lang-java
lang-js
lang-lisp
lang-lua
lang-ml
lang-perl
lang-php
lang-proto
lang-py
lang-rb
lang-scala
lang-sh
lang-sql
lang-vb
lang-xml
lang-vhdl

// タグ情報ページで以下で取得
$('#lang-class-value option').map(function() { return $(this).val() }).get().join("\n")
```

ぱっと見以下が足りません。自動的に選択肢の一覧を一気に更新できるなら、それがベストだと思います。

- lang-clj
- lang-coffee
- lang-go
- lang-json
- lang-latex
- lang-r
- lang-regex
- lang-rust

問題としては[se.meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234056/157841)に投稿されている問題と同じですが、ja.soの問題なので、こちらにも投稿します。